# Use array results from database as php variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The application I'm building requires some users to be linked to eachother.

There will be users and mentors. The database field "mentor_link" has a value. This value determines which users the mentor is linked to.

What I'm trying to do is search the database for the users with a certain "mentor_link" value and save their usernames as php variables to be used later.

Using json_encode() AND print_r simply displays something that looks like this:

[{"userName":"dave","0":"dave"},{"userName":"ely","0":"ely"},{"userName":"mentor1","0":"mentor1"}]

What I'm looking for is to target each username and save it as a variable. For example: $user1 = dave; $user2 = ely; etc etc.

All the other examples I've found only allow me to display it the same way as above.

My code is as follows:

```html
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT userName FROM tbl_users WHERE mentor_link=101");
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($result);
```

The database is connected fine and I'm able to pull single values based on the users details but I can't figure out how to get info on other users and display it/save it as a variable.

Oh and I'm using PDO to connect to the database.

Comment: Why create a php variable from each user in your table? :O

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to asking questions on here and I'm not so great at putting my point across. WHY I'm doing it is because I'm building a function where mentors can chat to their users. I need to use the usernames of the users they're connected to allow them to select which users to chat to. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this line:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

You can do anything with that data

```
print_r($result[0]);//user1
print_r($result[1]);//user2
```

or

```
$user1 = $result[0]; 
$user2 = $result[1];
```

then

```
echo $user1['userName'];//dave
echo $user2['userName'];//ely
```

Comment: Perfect! You sir are my saving grace today! Thanks! I really should've seen that. I'm fairly new to PHP